# Iterating Multiple Multimaps

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, multimap

I'am having problems while trying to iterate some maps.
Basically i have a Deposit class. Each deposit class has a multimap containing a destination Deposit and a distance. (This will be used to create a graph).
When i try to iterate all the maps i'm getting a segmentation fault error.

Here's the code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < deposit.size(); j++) {
    for (typename multimap< Deposit<Product>*, int>::iterator it = deposit.at(j)->getConnections().begin(); it != deposit.at(j)->getConnections().end(); it++) {
        cout << "From the depo. " << deposit.at(j)->getKey() << " to " << it->first->getKey()     << " with the distance " << it->second << endl;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

**Deposit Class:**

```
template<class Product>
class Deposit {
 private:
  multimap <Deposit<Product>*, int> connections;
 public:
  void addConnection(Deposit<Product>* dep, int dist);
  multimap <Deposit<Product>*, int> getConnections() const;
 }; 
(...)
template<class Product>
void Deposit<Product> ::addConnection(Deposit<Product>* depKey, int dist) {
this->connections.insert(pair<Deposit<Product>*, int>(depKey, dist));
}

template<class Product>
multimap < Deposit<Product>*, int> Deposit<Product> ::getConnections() const {
return this->connections;
}
```

**Storage Class - This is where I populate the multimaps.**

```
(...)
    ligs = rand() % 10;
    do{
        ligIdx = rand() % deposit.size();
        dist = rand() % 100;
        deposit.at(i)->addConnection(deposit.at(ligIdx), dist);
        ligs--;
    }while(ligs>0);
(...)
```

My deposit class has 2 subclasses. I dont know why the error occurs. Is there any problem with the iterator?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Can you show us how you populate your multimap and how you create the `Deposit<Product>` pointers ?

Comment: I've added more information. Let me know if there's anything else i can give. Thank you.

Comment: ok, the class definition prooved to be very useful : it's not the allocation, but the way you've defined a getter member function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is pretty nasty: `getConnections()` returns a multimap by value.

This means that successive calls to `deposit.at(j)->getConnections()` refer to different temporary copies of the original multimap.   Thus the the iterator created on the begin of the first temporary copy, will never match the end of the second copy, without first accessing illegally some invalid places.

Two alternatives:

- if you want to iterate on a copy,  make one local copy `auto cnx = deposit.at(j)->getConnections();` and change your inner loop to iterate on cnx.
- if you intended to iterate on the original multimap, change the signature of  `getConnections()` to return a reference.

*By the way, if you use c++11 or higher, you could consider defining the iterator in a more readable way:  `for (auto it = ....)` or even better, using the range-for syntax as proposed by Norah Attkins in her answer.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have a c++11 (or 14) compiler (and you should - unless it's a work/company barrier involved) consider using range based `for` loops to make your code clearer

```
for (auto const& elem : deposit) 
{
    for (auto const& product : elem) 
    {
    }
}
```

Apart from the stylist guidance, lacking info on what the containers actrually hold, we'd just be guessing what's wrong when answering this question. My guess is that invalid reads happen and the pointers you're accessing are not allocated (but that's a guess)

Comment: althoug this is perfectly valid and true, it doesn't answer the question of the OP and looks more like a comment.